# How do I setup a multiuser Pulseaudio Bluetooth configuration

Tags: pulseaudio, bluetooth

While investigating sporadic Bluetooth connection problems in my workstation (Ubuntu 22.04), I discovered that other instances of pulseaudio in the same machine, started by other users, somehow capture the bluetooth sink from pulseaudio and steal the device from my instance of pulseaudio. The settings is that I use the workstation as a Desktop with a monitor, but other colleagues also use the workstation via SSH.

When this happens I can see the device in `bluetoothctl`, both from my user `user` and from others:

```
user@ws:~$ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[CHG] Controller <...> Pairable: yes
[CHG] Controller <...> Pairable: yes
[WH-1000XM5]# info <MAC address of device>
Device <MAC address of device> (public)
    Name: WH-1000XM5
    Alias: WH-1000XM5
    Class: 0x00240404
    Icon: audio-headset
    Paired: yes
    Trusted: yes
    Blocked: no
    Connected: yes
    WakeAllowed: yes
    [...]
[WH-1000XM5]#
```

but I cannot see the sink in pulseaudio, neither from `pavucontrol` nor from `pactl` or `pacmd`:

```
user@ws:~$ pactl list short sinks

0   alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
1   alsa_output.usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00.iec958-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
```

and the headphones are not usable.

As reported in [Bluetooth Headset](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/bluetooth_headset#Connecting_works,_but_there_is_no_sound) from Arch Wiki, this situation can happen when GDM starts its own pulseaudio daemon and it steals the sink. In my case the pulseaudio daemons are started by other users.

Ideally, as the bluetooth headset is personal, only my user should be able to see the device, and certainly my pulseaudio daemon should maintain exclusive ownership of the sink.

To solve this issue, my initial thought is to remove bluetooth configuration from the system wide config file `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and only load the bluetooth modules in my personal file in `~/.config/pulse`.

However, this could prevent other users to use *their* bluetooth headset in my workstation. This situation is rare and I might never need something like this, but I would love to hear other possible solutions that avoid this issue, if available.